# Android Messaging Style notification -Add icon from image URL - Person.Builder

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications, kotlin-coroutines, coil

I am using Person Object to build chat app notifications like Gmail. So I have created the person object. But i want to set icon from a image URL coming from server an not from drawable resource. I am using Coil library for loading images . The below code is working fine,[image: please see this screen shot]

By default the android generates the icon with the first letter passed to the title.
So, How can i show the image coming from server as a URL in icon with best practice of memory and resource usages. Below is my Person object.
Here is the Official link of [Person](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Person.Builder).
And this is what I referred to [Notification Messaging style tutorial](https://itnext.io/android-messagingstyle-notification-as-clear-as-possible-1847f809ad59)

```
    val senderPerson: Person = Person.Builder().also {person->
        person.setKey(message.getSenderKey(prefs))
        person.setName(message.getNotificationTitle())
        person.setImportant(true)
//****HERE I WANT TO SET IMAGE FROM URL******
        //    person.setIcon(IconCompat.createWithResource(this, R.drawable.placeholder_transaparent))
    }.build()
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd load the image URL asynchronously using the [Coil Request](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/#requests), and return the fetched icon in a closure.

Coil returns a drawable, and you can get Icon from a `Drawable` through a Bitmap using `IconCompat.createWithBitmap((drawable as BitmapDrawable).bitmap)`:

```
private fun asyncLoadIcon(imageUrl: String?, setIcon: (IconCompat?) -> Unit) {
    if (imageUrl.isNullOrEmpty())
        setIcon(null)
    else {
        // using COIL to load the image
        val request = ImageRequest.Builder(this)
            .data(imageUrl)
            .target { drawable ->
                setIcon(IconCompat.createWithBitmap((drawable as BitmapDrawable).bitmap)) //  // Return the fetched icon from the URL
            }
            .listener(object : ImageRequest.Listener { // Return null icon if the URL is wrong
                override fun onError(request: ImageRequest, result: ErrorResult) {
                    setIcon(null)
                }
            })
            .build()
        imageLoader.enqueue(request)
    }
}
```

This code returns a null icon if the URL is wrong or if it's empty/null.

Then build the notification message with that function:

```
asyncLoadIcon("https://my_icon_url.png") { // set the icon url

    val person = Person.Builder().apply {
        setName("John Doe")
        setIcon(it)
    }.build()
    
    // Build the notification with the person
    .....
    
}
```

For some enhancements, you'd enable caching, and disable hardware bitmaps; but I do recommend other libraries like Glide and Picasso.

```
.memoryCachePolicy(CachePolicy.ENABLED)
.diskCachePolicy(CachePolicy.ENABLED)
.allowHardware(false) // Disable hardware bitmaps
```

[image]